# Need a Advanced Search Filter - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, react-native-flatlist

I have a SearchBar and a simple FlatList. My logic for search filter is working fine but that is fine for simple search.
Example:
If my FlatList has three items

1. Visiting hour.
2. He knew the visit hour.
3. visit and hour.

In my SearchBar if i search **"visit h"** it will render only **item 2** -> **2.  He knew the visit hour.**

I want it to render all 3 items when i search **"visit h"**
My Search filter should look for every item that includes "visit" and "h".
It should also include "visit" in "visiting"

How can i capture this type of filter? Is there any js Library that can be used? Any efficient way to execute this search filter?

My current code is below:

```
export default class HomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            notifications: [],
            query: '',
            temp: []
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://140xya6a67.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/', {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    notifications: responseJson,
                    notificationRead: false,
                    temp: responseJson,
                })
            })
    };

    goToDetails() {
        return this.props.navigation.navigate(Details);
    }

    renderItem({item}) {
        return <NotificationItem item={item}
                    onPress={() => {this.goToDetails()}}/>
    }

    handleSearch(text) {
        const newData = _.filter(this.state.temp, (item) => {
            const itemData = item.Desc ? item.Desc.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();
            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({
            notifications: newData,
            query: text,
        });
    }

    renderContent() {
        let {notifications} = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar placeholder='type here...' lightTheme round value={this.state.query}
                           onChangeText={(text) => {this.handleSearch(text)}}/>
                <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={(item, id) => item.id}
                    data={notifications}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        let {fill, container} = styles;

        return (
            <View style={[fill, container]}>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple filter of your own, like below (not tested):

```js
handleSearch(text) {
  if (!text || text.length === 0) {
    this.setState({
      notifications: this.state.temp,
      query: text,
    });
    return;
  }

  const newData = _.filter(this.state.temp, item => {
    const itemData = item.Desc ? item.Desc.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
    const textParts = text.toUpperCase().split(' ');

    let shouldInclude = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
      const part = textParts[i];
      shouldInclude = shouldInclude && (itemData.indexOf(part) > -1);

      if (!shouldInclude) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
  this.setState({
    notifications: newData,
    query: text,
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi,  The Search logic you gave me works fine. I need to add one more requirement which i am unable to add. I have a flatlist with 2 items: Her Dog, My Cat. If i search for "Dog" the first item appears. So it is correct. If i search for " M Ca" the second item appears. So it is correct. Now if i type "Do Ca" i want both the items to appear. How do i achieve this type of filtering in your logic??? Please help

Comment: More like an Extended search logic.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing full-text search, or even fuzzy search.

If you have a small list of static data, you can do it purely on frontend during run time with library like [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/examples.html#search-string-array).

For dynamic data, you need a backend to tokenize and prepare the data beforehand. Frontend then just send what the user has typed, and get feed the search result from backend.

You can build that yourself if you use a modern RDBMS like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html) or [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search). Or use services or tools more purposefully built for this problem, like [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch).

Comment: Fuse.js Thanks for that